# What is causing the strange behavior with duplicate values in react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Suppose you have defined a form using `useForm` and `useFieldArray` in react-hook-form.

Set initialState `name` and `age` to **undefined**.

Then, after executing the `remove` method, add the initial value with the `append` method.

Then the `name` and `age` of the newly added user are not `undefined`, but retain the values of the previously added user.

How is the internal logic handled?

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-grass-r255x1?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import { uniqueId } from "lodash"
import { Controller, useFieldArray, useForm } from "react-hook-form"

// Newly added values are expected to be undefined
const initialState = () => ({ id: uniqueId(), name: undefined, age: undefined })

const ReactHookForm = () => {
  const users = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "test1",
      age: 4,
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "test2",
      age: 5,
    },
  ]

  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm({ defaultValues: { users } })
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "users" })

  return (
<form className="mx-auto w-[50%]" onSubmit={handleSubmit((users) => console.log(users))}>
      <h1>RHF</h1>
      <button className="bg-[blue] text-[white]" type="button" onClick={() => append(initialState())}>
        append
      </button>
      {fields.map((user, i) => (
        <div key={user.id} className="mb-4 bg-white">
          <button className="bg-[red] text-[white]" type="button" onClick={() => remove(i)}>
            remove
          </button>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name={`users.${i}.name`}
            render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
              <div>
                <label className="w-[30%]">name</label>
                <input className="w-[70%]" type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
              </div>
            )}
          />
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name={`users.${i}.age`}
            render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
              <div>
                <label className="w-[30%]">age</label>
                <input className="w-[70%]" type="number" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </form>
  )
}

export default ReactHookForm
```

By changing the initial value from undefined to null, I got the expected initial value, but I don't know why!

If undefined, will it be overwritten with the default value?

Comment: From the react-hook-form [useForm documentation (rules)](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/#defaultValues): "_You should provide none undefined default value, as undefined value is conflicting with controlled component as default state_"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Default value for `useForm` is set. However, when the value passed to the argument of `append` contains undefined, it behaves strangely.

Comment: Ok..go ahead and keep using `undefined` then...you know...those pesky value conflicts. Good luck.